# Apply filter in data.table as in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, data.table

Translate `dplyr::filter` into data.table code.

Let's supposse I have:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

dt <- data.table(
  A = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE),
  B = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
  C = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
)

      A     B     C
1: TRUE  TRUE FALSE
2: TRUE FALSE  TRUE
3: TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Using `dplyr::filter`, I can get rows where all columns are `TRUE`:

```
dt |> dplyr::filter(if_all(where(is.logical)))

      A    B    C
1: TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

How can I translate this filter using`data.table` code? This is, selecting all logical columns and retrieving rows where all TRUE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

```
dt[dt[, rowSums(.SD) == ncol(.SD),      .SDcols = is.logical]]

dt[dt[, as.logical(do.call(pmin, .SD)), .SDcols = is.logical]]
```

Comment: code golf: `dt[, .SD[rowSums(!.SD) == 0,]]` (unfortunately `.SD` does not work in the `i=` arg, so we need to nest it once) (and yours is faster)

Comment: well, since all columns are logical you wouldn't need to define/use `.SD`: `dt[rowSums(!dt) == 0,]`

Comment: @mnist Right. Since the dplyr example included `where(is.logical)` I assumed this was not the case for OP's actual data.frame.